# I want to get the Most visited article from every category (4 categories)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have **4 categories** in a table in database.
I want to get the four articles most visited from every category in database.
This means that get `(4 articles most visited from category1)` + `(4 articles most visited from category2)` + `(4 articles most visited from category3)` + `(4 articles most visited from category4)` =  Total `16 articles` from `4 categories`.

and I want to doing that by one query.

Normal query:

```
$sql="select ID,name,country from article where `active`='yes' order by `visit` desc limit 16 ";
```

**The articles table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `article` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `town` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  `other_town` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '0',
  `size` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  `type` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  `tel` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  `mobile` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  `connect` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  `email` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  `photo1` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `print` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  `small_pic1` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `detail` text NOT NULL,
  `add_by` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `cat` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `goods_type` enum('new','old') NOT NULL,
  `add_date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `end_date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `period` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  `visit` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `comment` int(30) NOT NULL default '0',
  `fav` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
  `favorite` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
  `active` varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
  `rate` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `short` text NOT NULL,
  `add_to` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `author` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `author_img` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `lang` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
  `budget` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

**The categories table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `img` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `sub` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `type` varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  `lang` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
  `active` varchar(25) NOT NULL default '',
  `add_by` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Can you supply your table definitions?

Comment: It would be good if you can provide example of table structure.

Comment: and what you have been trying so far.

Comment: @Surasin Tancharoen: I don't know how can I do it

Comment: I cannot see a relationship between article and category. I guess you may have another table call article_cateogy?

Comment: `cat` in the `article` table? :)

Comment: @Surasin Tancharoen:I think we don't need any relationship because all data what we need in one table `articles table`

Comment: @Terry Seidler: yes `cat` in `article` table and represents cat id . and all data what we need in `articles table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, country, catCnt 
FROM (SELECT ID, NAME, country, cat, IF(@cat=(@cat:=cat), @cnt:=@cnt+1, @cnt:=1) catCnt 
      FROM (SELECT ID, NAME, country, cat FROM article WHERE `active`='yes' ORDER BY cat, `visit` DESC) A, 
           (SELECT @cat := 0, @cnt:=1) B
      ) A 
GROUP BY cat HAVING catCnt <= 4;
```

**OR**

```
SELECT ID, NAME, country
FROM (SELECT ID, NAME, country, cat, IF(@cat=(@cat:=cat), @cnt:=@cnt+1, @cnt:=1) catCnt 
      FROM (SELECT ID, NAME, country, cat FROM article WHERE `active`='yes' ORDER BY cat, `visit` DESC) A, 
           (SELECT @cat := 0, @cnt:=1) B
      ) A 
WHERE catCnt <= 4;
```

Comment: Error message: `Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: Thanks for your trying: it's working but not exactly what I want. I want to get 4 articles most visited from every categor. your query get more than 4 articles and not sorted .

Comment: @LionKing Use group by to solve the issue. It will give you 4 rows for each category

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your complex query to edit it.
can you please edit it and add group by.
thanks for help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24456/discussion-between-saharsh-shah-and-lion-king)

Comment: Thanks, but this time gives me one article from every category.
but I want 4 articles from every category.

Comment: Thanks for help, I wish you happy luck

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, but it is not 100% straight forward. I bookmarked this article from a SO question I had previously read (will try and find/link that as well). Basically if you want this one group per query you can just use ORDER BY and LIMIT, but to do all in one query follow the linked article which walks through this in detail.

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

For posterity I will try and post an example summary query based on the first method he provides, which can grow exponentially in time proportional to the number of categories:

```
select ID, name, country, cat, visit
from article
where visit = (select max(visit) from article as a where a.cat = article.cat)
or visit = (select max(visit) from article as a where a.cat = article.cat
   and visit < (select max(visit) from article as a2 where a2.cat = article.cat))

or visit = (select max(visit) from article as a where a.cat = article.cat
  and a.visit < (select max(a2.visit) from article as a2 where a2.cat = article.cat
  and a2.visit < (select max(a3.visit) from article as a3 where a3.cat = article.cat)))

or visit = (select max(visit) from article as a where a.cat = article.cat
  and a.visit < (select max(a2.visit) from article as a2 where a2.cat = article.cat
  and a2.visit < (select max(a3.visit) from article as a3 where a3.cat = article.cat
  and a3.visit < (select max(a4.visit) from article as a4 where a4.cat =    article.cat))))
order by cat, visit desc
```

Or if you want the order by with out specifying category, just order by visit desc

This will return the top four in each category, but note the nesting of the query per level deep you are looking to go, follow his instructions for better options if you need to keep going deeper (he, and I would describe this as YUCK).

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e115f/26

Also for posterity, my test data:

```
CREATE TABLE article (
 ID int auto_increment primary key, 
 name varchar(20), 
 country varchar(30),
 cat int,
 visit int
);

INSERT INTO article (name, country, cat, visit) VALUES
 ('Test1', 'Canada', 1, 7),('Test2', 'Canada', 1, 2),('Test3', 'Ireland', 1, 1),
 ('Test5', 'Ireland', 1, 3),('Test6', 'Ireland', 1, 8),('Test7', 'India', 1, 9),
 ('Test8', 'Canada', 2, 11),('Test9', 'Canada', 2, 13),('Test10', 'Ireland', 2, 6),
 ('Test11', 'Ireland', 2, 5),('Test12', 'Ireland', 2, 1),('Test13', 'India', 3, 1),
 ('Test14', 'India', 3, 9),('Test15', 'India', 3, 8),('Test16', 'India', 3, 54);
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, don't gives me most visited from every category, and also not sorted.

Comment: @LionKing It does, look at the fiddle. Added visits so you can see it explicitly. Also ordering is just an order by clause, also added.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.  Basically determine a row number per category, then order by visit column and select the top 4.  This is a condensed version, but should get the point across (add the fields you need returned):

```
SELECT Id, Cat, Visit, Name
FROM (
    SELECT 
      @curRow:=CASE WHEN @prevRow = A.cat THEN @curRow+1 ELSE 1 END AS rn,
      A.Id, 
      A.Visit,
      A.Cat, A.Name, 
      @prevRow:=A.cat AS clset
    FROM (SELECT A.Id, C.Id as Cat, A.Visit, C.Name
          FROM Articles A
            JOIN Category C ON A.cat = C.id
          ORDER BY A.Cat, A.Visit DESC
          ) A
      JOIN (SELECT @curRow:=0) r
      JOIN (SELECT @prevRow:=0) r2
  ) B
  WHERE rn <= 4
```

And some Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7260/1

Good luck.

Comment: Error message: Table 't9-fast.articles' doesn't exist

Comment: @LionKing -- I wrote this before you posted your code -- replace field names and table names accordingly :)  You don't have an articles table -- yours is article... Best of luck!